# Is every tensor passed as fetches to the run method of the session evaluated?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose we have the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf


temp = {"first": tf.Variable(1.0), "second": tf.Variable(2.0)}

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(temp)
    print(temp["first"])
    print(temp["second"])
```

If you do `sess.run()` on a dictionary (e.g. `temp`) that contains two TensorFlow variables, are these two variables going to be evaluated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run) for the `run` method of the `Session` class states

> `run(fetches, feed_dict=None, options=None, run_metadata=None)`
>
> Runs operations and evaluates tensors in `fetches`.
>
> This method runs one "step" of TensorFlow computation, by running the necessary graph fragment to execute every Operation and evaluate every Tensor in `fetches`, substituting the values in `feed_dict` for the corresponding input values.
>
> The fetches argument may be a single graph element, or an arbitrarily nested list, tuple, namedtuple, dict, or OrderedDict containing graph elements at its leaves.

In your case, `temp` (a `dict`) is the "`fetches`" that you pass to `run`. So, every operation or tensor in `temp` is evaluated.

If I didn't miss anything, the documentation doesn't say anything about the order of evaluation and, I think, you should not assume that an operation or a tensor is evaluated in a specific order, given that this may be subject to changes (e.g. due to optimizations).

So, to answer your question directly: yes, every variable/tensor (passed as `fetches` to the `run` method of the session) is evaluated.

Furthermore, note that you also have a problem with your code, which should e.g. be

```
import tensorflow as tf


temp = {"first": tf.Variable(1.0), "second": tf.Variable(2.0)}

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(temp)
    print(temp["first"])
    print(temp["second"])
```

As the [documentation for `Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) states

> When you launch the graph, variables have to be explicitly initialized before you can run Ops that use their value.

Comment: Thanks! And yes, I just wrote some little code so you could get the gist and I happened to miss over that.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the correct syntax would be like this

```
results = sess.run(temp.values())
for name, val in zip(temp, results):
  print name, val
```

Comment: This does not answer the question at all! And, no, the way the OP is printing the values in the dictionary is also valid.